# get the value of anchor ( = location.hash) and send it with python POST request

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests, anchor

i'm trying to log in to a webpage using python,,,
when sending the post requests i see 4 parameters are sent in the request body(using burp suite) : (username,password,logintoken,anchor)
i've got the first 3,but when trying to get the value of the 'anchor' i see that:

input id="anchor" type="hidden" name="anchor" value=""
scrpt>document.getElementById('anchor').value = location.hash;</scrpt

so it's value is a JS =location.hash
how can i extract it and send it with the POST request?

here is the site: [https://elearning.yu.edu.jo/]

full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bb
url = "https://84.16.252.74/login/index.php"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69'} 
s = requests.Session()
y = s.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
d=(s.cookies).get_dict()
soup = bb(y.text, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("input", attrs={'name': 'logintoken'})
tok=div.attrs['value']
dd = {'username': my_username, 'password': 
'my_pass',"logintoken":tok,'anchor':""}
ss = requests.post(url, data=dd,verify=False,headers=headers,cookies=d)
if "Dashboard" in ss.text:
  print('Success')
```

would it be because i turned the "certificate verify" to False?

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212).

Comment: Can it be also in the url as www.example.com/parts#some-part ?

Comment: @Deniz,,it is not there,,here is the site:
https://elearning.yu.edu.jo/

Comment: It seems you can already post with an empty anchor value?

Comment: no :(,,do u need source code?

Comment: would it be because i've turned the certificate verify to False?

Comment: Why are you using an IP and not the domain?

Comment: @gre_gor no reason,,it's just the same

Comment: @gre_gor if i turn the "Verify" to False there is no error thrown,,it sends the POST request,but when reading the response it is not success

Answer (score 0):

For an URL like `http://www.example.com/index.php#test`

`location.hash` will return `#test`

**hash** return the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.

so i think you can pass empty string to anchor parameter

Comment: i've tried but Unfortunately no,,would it be because i've turned the certificate verify to False?